# Functions, sets, intersections

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

---

Question:

Let $S = \{1,2\} = T$ and define $f: S \to T$ by $f(1) = 1 = f(2)$. Let $B = \{1\}$ and let $C = \{ 2\}$. Find $f[B \cap C]$ and $f[B] \cap f[C]$ and observe they are not equal.

Hint: Thus intersections are not always preserved in passing to images.

---

My attempt:
\begin{align*}
B \cap C & = \emptyset\\
f(B \cap C) & = \emptyset\\
f[B] & = f[1] = 1\\
f[C] & = f[2] = 1\\
f[B] \cap f[C] & = f[1] \cap f[2] = \{1\}
\end{align*}

---

This seems right but I wanna be 100% sure.

Comment: Yes, you did this right.

Comment: You basically have the right idea, but your set notation isn't as good as it could be.  For instance, $f[B]=\{1\}$.  Or, in more detail, $f[B]=\{f(1)\}=\{1\}$

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.